# I want to check whether all elements(integers) from starting to ending in an array are equal

Tags: c

In an array, I have to check whether all elements are same.
For example:
`a[]={2,2,2,2,2,2,2}`

```
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        if(a[0] == a[i])
        {
            f = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(f == 1)
    printf("All elements are same");
```

It is giving me true, when any two elements are same. But I have to check whether all elements are same or not.

Comment: Reverse the logic of your code. Set the flag and break out if two elements are *not* equal instead.

Comment: seems like an answer to me

Comment: You need to think clearly about what you're doing.  Look at the code.  The very first time through the loop, it is comparing `a[0]` with itself, setting `f` to 1, and exiting the loop.  Clearly not right.  And even if you skip the first element, suppose `a[0]` and `a[1]` are the same and everything else differs.  The same thing will happen.  If *any* pair differ, then you need to set `f` to 0.  So initialize `f` to 1, and if any pair differ, set it to 0 and exit the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Just invert the logic, really. And you can start iterating from 1, since you're comparing to `a[0]`:

```
f = 1;
for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  if (a[i] != a[0]) {
    f = 0;
    break;
  }

if (f == 1)
  printf("All elements are the same");
```

Comment: Maybe initialise f to `TRUE` and set it to `FALSE` if, for some i, `a[i] != a[0]` . The test at the end then becomes `if(f) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, more similar to your idea than other answers

```
f = 0; // start with 0 equals
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    if(a[0] == a[i])
    {
        f += 1; // add 1 when finds pair of equals
        // break; // don't break: look at **ALL** elements
    }
}
if(f == n) /* if total pairs is total elements */
printf("All elements are same");
```

Note: this approach has to look at **ALL** elements. It is much more efficient to use an approach that minimizes the number of elements to compare.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea for check if all list items are equal, is to find **min** and **max**, and compere them.

- **If they are equal** - that means that the whole list (or arry and etc.) is equal.
- **If they are not equal** - that means that not the whole list is equal.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
f = 1;
...
if(a[0] != a[i])
{
  f = 0;
  break;
}
...
if(f == 1)
    printf("All elements are same");
```

Comment: I think pure code answers are as less helpful as pure link answers a bit of explanation should not be too much work.

Comment: @Yastanub Alternatively a professional or enthusiast programmer can look at the original code for 5 seconds and figure out the solution themselves - that's not too much work either. This is such utterly trivial stuff that no explanation should be needed.

Comment: If OP struggles with such a trivial problem it is pretty much a good idea to give an explanation. You cant compare a professional programer to a beginner you need to relativate their skill levels and their comprehensiveness. A professional programmer can for sure look at that code in 5 seconds and understand it but for an absolute beginner it might be not that understandable. Just imagine what a moderate problem like some algorithm. A professional programmer would udnerstand the code without explanation but someone with less knowledge might not. Would you leave the explanation out there?

Comment: @Yastanub This is supposedly a site for professional or enthusiast programmers, not an interactive beginner tutorial. But sure, I can as well delete this answer, down vote the OP for posting chapter 1 beginner-level questions and move on. I'm sure they'll thank you.

Comment: What do you define as an "enthusiast" programmer? I could know very little about programming but could be very enthusastic to learn more about it and then search for help in SO. If you want to help especially beginners you should include an explanation. If you dont want to help them ignore them. If you dont like them/dont want them to post here downvote them if that pleases you.

Comment: @Yastanub "Enthusiast" is SO's very subjective definition that's been around since day 1, [see this for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258081/should-professionals-and-enthusiasts-be-qualified-in-the-help-center). Historically, the site has gone from mostly professional programmers helping each other, to the homework garbage dump that it is today. I suspect an "enthusiast" with SO's current definition today is someone who can type stuff with a keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194485/discussion-between-yastanub-and-lundin).